# How to override FabricJS mouse cursor

Tags: fabricjs

When using `FabricJS`, how can you temporarily change the mouse cursor even if you're hovering a shape that has its own curser defined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Override setCursor

You can override the `fabric.js` canvas function `setCursor` and implement your own logic for detecting what the mouse cursor should really be.

```js
fabric.Canvas.prototype.setCursor = function (value) {
    if (something) value = 'pointer'; // Add your own logic here to override
    this.upperCanvasEl.style.cursor = value;
};
```

Place the code above in your own javascript file, so that you can upgrade `fabric.js` later without losing your modifications. Make sure you load this file *after* you load `fabric.js`. Modify the `if` statement to match your own logic that determines whether a different cursor should be used.

Answer (score 3):

```js
Fabric.defaultCursor = "move";  // "crosshair"
```

*defaultCursor* is used to set "Default cursor value used for the entire canvas"

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvasID');
canvas.defaultCursor = 'crosshair';
```

For more details see the docs:
http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Canvas.html#defaultCursor

Comment: I doubt that this helps, or even works at all. To covince me otherwise please explain how this works and why it is supposed to help.